# vTiger Custom Module suddenly stopped storing data

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

My custom module has suddenly stopped storing data in the base table and no filters are showing up either.

Comment: Provide some more information like how did you created your custom module, is your custom module has relationship with your other modules? did you update any relationship or did you create same module many times by deleting and adding??? If you delete and add same module many times you have to clear everything related to that module. Please post all detail.

Comment: Yes, i have created and deleted the module many times. i guess this is how we add things to a module, right?. My module has relationship with Contacts and Leads. I tried to delete the module using console.php and deleted the 3 related tables as well but now when i create the same module again it doesn't store the records at all.

Answer (score -1):

Try Deleting module using following script and as well as using console.php. 
Put and run from your root directory (using browser)

```
<?php
include_once('vtlib/Vtiger/Module.php');
$Vtiger_Utils_Log = true;
$MODULENAME = 'ModuleName';  //module name to delete
$moduleInstance = Vtiger_Module::getInstance($MODULENAME);
if($module) {
    $module->delete();
}

//DB adjustment needs to be done -- Running this script is not enugh.
echo "Success";
```

Remember while deleting module, everything must be deleted.
Check Following table after deleting module using above **script** and **console.php**

- vtiger_field
- vtiger_relatedlists
- vtiger_<--Your-Module-Name-->
- vtiger_<--Your-Module-Name-->_user_field
- vtiger_<--Your-Module-Name-->cf

The **first two** table are important, search your module and related fields on those two tables and delete that row. And last three tables you need to delete completely. But dont ever delete last three tables directly.

Comment: I did this whole process but still the module is not storing data, It says Success when storing data from quick form but there is nothing when i can the records.